# Phonegap media record does not work for 2nd time

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am trying to record audio using phonegap. When i click my record button, function recordAudio() executes successfully. But for the 2nd time log gives error. Audio source is ok, but I dont know what that error means. Here is the error:

```
E/AudioRecord( 40): could not get audio input for record source 1
e/stagefrightrecorder ( 40): audio source is not initialized
e/mediarecorder( 2676): start failed -2147483648
d/cordovalog( 2676): file:///android_asset/www/phonegap.js: line 862 : uncaught error: error calling method on NPObject
```

Here is my code:

```
var my_mediaRec=null;
        var recInterval=null;
        // Record audio
        //
        function recordAudio(){

            my_mediaRec = new Media(fs_path+"/recording"+lesson_no+".mp3", onSuccessRecord, onError);

            // Record audio
            my_mediaRec.startRecord();

            recInterval = setInterval(function() {
                endWord++;
                placeRecordMarker(endWord)
            }, 1000);

        }
```

Comment: Can you please provide more of your HTML code? I think the problem is with how you are recording, not with the cordova/phonegap code itself. (I think this because I took the audio recording sample from docs.cordova.io and was able to record multiple times in a row, never getting this error.) Did you make sure to call stopRecording()?

Comment: I have posted the 1 Answer with more code. Stop button does stop the recording and file is saved. But it gives the error for the 2nd time

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this? Am seeing a similar error on my java application. It records successfully the first time, but fails the next time

Answer (score 0):

Here is html:

```
<div id="record-buttons">
                        <div class="record-mic" onclick="record_mic()"></div>
                        <div class="record-stop" onclick="record_play()"></div>
                        <div class="record-play" onclick="record_stop()"></div>
                    </div>
```

Here is js:

```
    function record_play(){
        if(recording==true){
            $('.record-play').show();
            $('.record-stop').hide();
            endWord=startWord;
            recordAudio();
        }
    } 
    function record_stop(){
        if(recording==true){
            $('.record-stop').show();
            $('.record-play').hide();
            startWord=endWord;
            stopRecordAudio();

        }
    } 

var my_mediaRec=null;
        var recInterval=null;
        // Record audio
        //
        function recordAudio(){

            my_mediaRec = new Media(fs_path+"/recording"+lesson_no+".mp3", onSuccessRecord, onError);

            // Record audio
            my_mediaRec.startRecord();

            recInterval = setInterval(function() {
                endWord++;
                placeRecordMarker(endWord)
            }, 1000);

        }

        // Set record position
        //
        /*function setRecordPosition(position){
            $('.audio-position').html(position);
            //placeMarker(position)
        }*/

        function stopRecordAudio(){
            clearInterval(recInterval);
            my_mediaRec.stopRecord();
        }
```